# How std::find_if works with a list of pointer?

Tags: if-statement, find, predicate

Please consider the following code blocks:

```
1- //.h
     std::list<Item> itemsList;
```

.............

```
 //.cpp

  2-   struct ItemExist: public std::binary_function< Item, int, bool > 
            {
              bool operator () ( const Item&sc, const int &number ) const 
                {
                return sc.orderNumber == number;
                }
             };
```

.....

```
3-    std::list<Item>::iterator itd= std::find_if(itemList.begin(),itemList.end(),std::bind2nd( ItemExist(),orderNumber ) );
```

......
Item is a class with a property called orderNumber

1^ block: an item list is declared

2^ block: a Predicate class is defined

3^ block: a given Item is searched trougth the list.

All works fine.

Whishing I use a list of  pointer to item, i should change declaration into block 1 like this:

```
 std::list<Item*> itemsList;
```

And the search block -3 becomes:

```
 std::list<Item*>::iterator itd= std::find_if(itemList.begin(),itemList.end(),std::bind2nd( ItemExist(),orderNumber ) );
```

At this point i have a problem with (i think) the predicate class. The compiler says:

```
[C++ Error] _algobase.c(183): E2064 Cannot initialize 'const Item&' with 'Item *'
[C++ Error] _algobase.c(183): E2342 Type mismatch in parameter '__x' (wanted 'const Item&', got 'Item *')
```

So, question is: how i should fix the predicate (block 2) to get it all working?
I can't figure it out. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

my try was:

```
struct ItemExist: public std::binary_function< Item*, int, bool > {
  bool operator () ( const Item *sc, const int &number ) const {
    return sc->orderNumber== number;
    }
  };
```

It seems to work but i am not sure it is the rigth solution.